# Getting URL,Title and excerpt of Individual post inside template-Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I tried adding a social share script inside index template, when i click share burron i want to get the URL of Individual post.I defined the structure inside javascript.

```
<a class="fb-share" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="facebook('Link of the post', 'Title of the post','Excerpt of the post','Thumbnail of featured image');"></a>
```

I tried using link of the post  http://www.dreamstopixels.com/%postname% and failed. I need some suggestions Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some code inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) on your index template to get the data and generate the link.  Put the following inside the `while` loop after `the_post();` is called:

```
<?php
    $url = get_permalink();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');
?>
```

That sets up all the data you need, then you just build the anchor tag that calls the script and passes the data to facebook: (still within the loop)

```
<?php 
    $fbonclick = "facebook('".$link."','".$title."','".$excerpt."','".$image."');"; 
?>
```

Then to create the link itself:

```
<a class="fb-share" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="<?php echo $fbonclick; ?>"></a>
```

To be honest I'm not sure why you need to do it this way though, there are a thousand social share plugins out there.  Just use AddThis or something.

Comment: Thanks for your try but this code worked for me
`<a class="snippet-facebook snippet-share" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="facebook('<?php echo get_permalink();?>','<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>','<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>','<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>');"></a>
`

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing :) Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Try using thoses function:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt
```

There is a lot of docs on WORDPRESS CODEX. 
You should always keep it open when developping a wordpress template.

LAL.